# Error 500 при запуске Laravel (mac)

Tags: laravel, mac, xampp

[image: первая фотография][image: вторая фотография]Обращаюсь по проблеме запуска ларавел. Скачала composer и создала новый проект ларавел, но когда ввожу "http://192.168.64.2/newproject/public/", он выдает error500 (вторая фотография). При этом при вводе "http://192.168.64.2/newproject/", все папки находятся(первая фотография).
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? В чем может быть проблема?
Благодарю за помощь!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706113/server-error-500-when-accessing-laravel-5-8

Comment: Так вы не серверите её